# How exactly does attr_accessible protects the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've spend the last 4 hours trying to learn attr_accessible for rails (I'm a newbie trying to learn rails right now). Every single documentation/article have focused on how attr_accessible prevents certain attributes from getting modified by mass assignment. Great, but no one bothered to explain how it protects the db in other scenarios.

For example, I'm assuming mass assignment happens when a form is submitted for model creation. So in this example in the book, by declaring this in routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

I've made it possible to easily create/retrieve/update/delete with REST. I'm assuming mass assignment happens in create. And making certain attributes inaccessible makes sense. But what about update? attr_accessible doesn't say anything about single assignment. So any user can initiate a POST call to update any particular field. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

> So any user can initiate a POST call to update any particular field. What am I missing?

You missed CSRF protection.

Answer (score 0):

Don't seem to be missing anything. Most common example is this:

If you have a "type" or "access" column that controls who's an admin and who's not, and you don't protect it, I can use CURL to create myself as an admin with full privileges.